# Passing javascript variable to a python program(cgi imported)

Tags: javascript, python, variables, xmlhttprequest, cgi

Currently I am trying to pass a sequence of letters from HTML to a python program. I am having trouble connecting javascript to the python program. Currently my python program is only written to take the sequence and print it. For example:

## python code

```
import cgi
def main():
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    print(form)
main()
```

However I am struggling to write javascript function to take the variable of sequence and pass it to the above python program.

## java script

```
function takevariable(){
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
}
```

I understand I need to work with XMLHttpRequest() However, I could not take the step to begin writing that part.

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a API for receive the request from your JavaScript Code on Python ([Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) it's very simple and easy to learn) and make a httpRequest from your JS to your API on Python... The http request from your JS can be made with jQuery, or native JavaScript with XMLHttpRequest. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) an example.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I am trying to keep everything default instead of installing additional library or package. Because these html, js, python codes will be used with others. Is there other way to create the python API?